# How to send sms to multiple contacts

Tags: yii

How to send sms to multiple contacts and get the result code for each of them. It is not working. I get opened only the last number in the 'numbers' string and not to all of them.

What am I doing wrong?

In my controller,

```
  foreach ($sendarraystudent as $studentid) {
      //$i++;
      $student = Student::model()->findByPk($studentid);

      $name = $student->student_firstname . " " . $student->student_middlename . " " . $student->student_lastname;

      $smobile = $student->student_mobile;
      //$mobilelist = $mobilelist . ',' . $smobile;
      $msg1 = $msg;
      $msg1 = str_replace("#course#", $course->course_name, $msg);
      $msg1 = str_replace("#batch#", $batch->batch_name, $msg1);
      $msg1 = str_replace("#name#", $name, $msg1);

      $this->sendbulk($smobile, $msg1);
  }

protected function sendbulk($mobilenum, $message) {
    $no = $mobilenum;
    $msg = $message;

    $link = "http://url/api/v3/index.php?method=sms&api_key=A6xxxxxxxxxxx&to=" . $no . "&sender=xxxxxx&message=" . $msg . "&unicode=xxx";
    header('Location: ' . $link) and exit;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to integrate kapsystem sms gateway. I was reading API docs . There is 'URL' in each example call. But what is the URL? there is no mention of it. is URL = "http://trans.kapsystem.com" or something else? please help me.

Comment: Yes, URL means like  "trans.kapsystem.com" (sms gateway url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is because you use redirect `header('Location: ' . $link) and exit;`. Processing only one sms. Try this:

```
foreach ($sendarraystudent as $studentid) {
    //...
    $link = "http://url/api/v3/index.php?method=sms&api_key=A6xxxxxxxxxxx&to=" . $student->student_mobile . "&sender=xxxxxx&message=" . $msg1 . "&unicode=xxx"
    $content = file_get_contents($link);

    echo $content;
}
```

Comment: Not working this code also. By using this get error like,     
Error 500
file_get_contents(http://url/api/v3/index.php?method=sms&amp;api_key=A6xxxxxxxxxx&amp;to=99xxxxx&amp;sender=xxxxxxx&amp;message= Studnet Name :Nabil Nazim , Course : STD III , Batch : A&amp;unicode=x): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST